# ASP.NET navigate to anchor in code behind

Tags: asp.net, javascript, anchor

I have a simple Web Form with code like this:

```
//...
//tons of text
//...
<a name="message" />
//...
//tons of text
//...
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSend" 
                runat="server" 
                text="Send"
                onclick="ButtonSend_Click" />
```

After POST I want to navigate user to my anchor "message". I have following code for this:

```
protected void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                                        "navigate",
                                        "window.location.hash='#message';",
                                        true);
}
```

This simple JavaScript is not working in Firefox 3.5.2 - url is changing in browser but page is not navigated to anchor. In IE 8 it works perfectly.

Why this JavaScript code is not working in Firefox? Am I missing something?

Comment: seems to be working for me ... using FF 3.0.13 // IE8 both browser scrolled down perfectly ... i do think it should be working but you could try Cleiton code if ever its not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've solved my problem. JavaScript code was called before my anchor even existed. That's why Firefox wasn't scroll page down.

My code looks now like tihs:

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                                        "navigate",
                                        "window.onload = function() {window.location.hash='#message';}",
                                         true);
```

After page load I'm calling my simple JavaScript function.

The key to found solution was Cleiton answer. Firebug reports that getElementById was returning null reference. Then I looked at generated HTML like andrewWinn suggested - JavaScript was called before anchor existed. Made little googling and found solution.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: If you don't specify # in the message Firefox seems to add it by itself. Had tried to assign to ".hash" to write query parameters to the URL at the client side (without page refresh) with no success

Answer (score 5):

Mendoza, you can use native **scrollIntoView** function.

To do what you want, just write:

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                                        "navigate",
                                        "document.getElementById('id_of_the_element').scrollIntoView();",
                                        true);
```

Comment: Your solution is not working too :( Tested on Firefox 3.5.2 and IE 8. Also tested on different computer with Firefox 3.0.10 and IE 8 - not working. I just don't get it :/

Comment: @Mendoza, I tested it with IE6 and Firefox 3.5.2 and it worked fine. I think you did something wrong. For example, you anchor has to have an ID for this solution to work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this once.  Have you taken a look at the actual HTML?  If I remember, FireFox was being case sensative on the anchors.  I don't know if that changed recently or not.

Comment: This answer should be a comment.  It is a question for the original question author, and speculation with "i don't know"

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [jQuery LocalScroll plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/LocalScroll).  Using this, you could scroll using:

```
$(function() {
    $.scrollTo("#message");
});
```

Or with your ASP.NET code:

```
protected void ButtonSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                                            "navigate",
                                            "$(function() { $.scrollTo('#message'); });",
                                             true);
}
```

It's not an ideal solution, especially if you're not using jQuery anywhere in your project already, but it might solve your problem.