# Move a page to a bookmark link position

Tags: c#, javascript

In C# on the page callback, after the page logic is done I would like the page to jump to the bookmark position (`<a name="whatever">here</a>`).

I tried to use `Response.Redirect`, but it reloads the page and it doesn't do the preceding logic. I was thinking about using JavaScript for this purpose, but I only want this to be done on page call back

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307629/asp-net-navigate-to-anchor-in-code-behind

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the Hash tag in order for it to work.

```
<a href="#whatever">Move to Woot!!</a>


<a name="whatever">Woot!!</a>
```